# How to use constructors to the @repository in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I want to construct the @repository with some parameters:

```
@Repository
public class BasicRepository<T> {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private final Class typeParameterClass;
    public BasicRepository(Class typeParameterClass){
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }
    public void createCollection(T t) {
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(typeParameterClass)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(typeParameterClass);
        }
    }
}
```

In java configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BasicRepository<Topic> topicDao(){
        return new BasicRepository<Topic>(Topic.class);
    }
}
```

When I run the code ,it throws the exception about “Error creating bean with name 'basicRepository'” ，I think the annotation of "@Repository" doesnt have the constructors,I want to initialize the "typeParameterClass",Someone can explain how?

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception. ALWAYS do when asking about an exception.

Comment: I think you have many `BasicRepository`'s bean. Let's leave it for now. Paste the stack trace of the error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what appears to be happening is that the `component-scan` is finding your `@Repository` class and is trying to create a bean out of it, which it can't as it will not know how to instantiate your class with the `typeParameterClass` parameter.

The fix could be a few of them:

- Probably not a good approach may be to go ahead and remove the
  `@Repository` annotation as you are anyway generating the bean
  through `@Bean` annotation. The reason this is not a good option is
  because `@Repository` annotated beans behavior is modified at runtime
  . For eg, persistence exception translation to spring runtime types.
- One more option could be to retain `@Repository` annotation but
  prevent component scanning for this specific class or specific
  package.